# Instantiate a template for a vector

Tags: c++, templates, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename nameOfTheVariableTypeA, 
      typename nameOfTheVariableTypeB> nameOfTheVariableTypeB functionX 
                                               (nameOfTheVariableTypeA argA,
                                               (nameOfTheVariableTypeB argB)
{
    nameOfTheVariableTypeA tempArgA;
    nameOfTheVariableTypeB tempArgB;

    argA.push_back(22);

    tempArgA = argA;
    cout << "\ntempArgA: " << tempArgA[0] << "\n";

    tempArgB = argB;
    cout << "\ntempArgB: " << tempArgB << "\n";

    return tempArgB;
}

int main ()
{
    functionX (12, 12.4567);

    vector <int> f;
    functionX (f, 12.4567);

    return 0;
}
```

From a template book: 
`An attempt to instantiate a template for a type that doesn't support all the operations used within it will result in a compile-time error.`

The error I received for the above code is:

1. `error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘argA’, which is of non-class type ‘int’`
2. `error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer`

What's the point that I am missing?

Comment: Perhaps the code isn't supposed to compile? It might simply be a demonstration of what the book is talking about.

Comment: @In silico No, that code is "mine", I want to understand the cause of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, there's a superfluous parenthesis:

```
template <typename nameOfTheVariableTypeA,  
      typename nameOfTheVariableTypeB> nameOfTheVariableTypeB functionX  
                                               (nameOfTheVariableTypeA argA, 
                                              /*(*/nameOfTheVariableTypeB argB) 
// Note: extra parenthesis not needed here -----^ 
{
```

Assuming that's just a typo, let's take a look the first call to `functionX()`:

```
functionX(12, 12.4567);
```

Now, template functions require that all template parameters be specified before you can call them. But in certain cases the compiler can deduce the required type for `nameOfTheVariableTypeA` and `nameOfTheVariableTypeB` for the function call to work.

In this case, `12` is an integer literal, so it has type `int`. `12.4567` is a floating-point literal, so it has type `double`. Thus, within `functionX()`, `nameOfTheVariableTypeA` is of type `int` and `nameOfTheVariableTypeB` is of type `double`.

Now that all the template parameters have been specified (in this case, deduced), the compiler can *instantiate* the template function. That is, the compiler creates a function that looks like this:

```
// Hypothetical function generated by the compiler
double functionX_int_double(int argA, double argB)  
{  
    int tempArgA;  
    double tempArgB;  
    // ...
```

It's as though the compiler simply substituted `nameOfTheVariableTypeA` and `nameOfTheVariableTypeB` with the deduced types. Clearly, the argument `argA` and variable `tempArgA` has type `int`. You get the first error because `int` doesn't have a class member function called `push_back()`. It's the same reason why this won't work:

```
int i = 20;
i.push_back(22);
```

You also get the second error because the subscript operator `[]` is not defined for `int`s. Again, it's the same reason why this won't work:

```
int j = 21;
cout << j[0];
```

Note that this kind of information can be gleaned from the compiler errors themselves. Make sure you read them!

Comment: +1: I didn't see the extra paren, maybe because of the needlessly long type names...

Comment: @Rene Putting explanatory variable names is a helpful practice.

Comment: @Anisha Kaul: Self-explanatory names are good, but don't go overboad with them. :-) Be concise; for example `TypeA` and `TypeB` would be just as descriptive but requires much less effort to type.

Answer (score 1):

The call

```
functionX (12, 12.4567);
```

instantiantes a function with `(int, double)` parameters. The `int argA` does neither have a `push_back()` method nor an array index operator. So you cannot use `tempArgA[0]` also.

Answer (score 1):

In your first call to `functionX`:

```
functionX (12, 12.4567);
```

The type `nameOfTheVariableTypeA` within your template will be inferred as `int`. Obviously the `int` type doesn't support `push_back()` or `operator[]`.

Answer (score 1):

A complete code of yours with template specialization :) . As said by other's there is no push_back function for "int" and therefore you need specialized implementation for that.

```
template < typename nameOfTheVariableTypeA,
      typename nameOfTheVariableTypeB >
nameOfTheVariableTypeB functionX (nameOfTheVariableTypeA argA,nameOfTheVariableTypeB argB)
{
    nameOfTheVariableTypeA tempArgA;
    nameOfTheVariableTypeB tempArgB;

    argA.push_back(22);

    tempArgA = argA;
    cout << "\ntempArgA: " << tempArgA[0] << "\n";

    /*tempArgB = argB;
    cout << "\ntempArgB: " << tempArgB << "\n";*/

    return tempArgB;
}
template < >
float functionX < int,float > (int argA,float argB){

        int tempArgA;
    int tempArgB;

        tempArgA = argA;
    cout << "\ntempArgA: " << tempArgA << "\n";

        return tempArgB;
}


int main ()
{
    functionX < int,float >(12, 12.4567);

    vector < int > f;
    functionX < vector < int > , float > (f, 12.4567);

    return 0;
}
```